# how to update field of attendance via an attendance request modification

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

i'm using odoo 11. i'm working on the attendance module i want to create an attendance modification request  which be approuved by the manager (to create a new attendance or modify an attendance already existe) and the attendances automatically updated. the probleme is when i press approuve my request was approuved but the attendances were not updated (in the hr.attendance model). Any idea for help please ?? 
 here is  my code

regularization.py

```
class Regular(models.Model):

_name = 'attendance.regular'
_rec_name = 'employee'
_description = 'Approval Request'
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']

def _get_employee_id(self):
    employee_rec = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.uid)], limit=1)
    return employee_rec.id

reg_category = fields.Many2one('reg.categories',
                                string='Regularization Category', required=True)
from_date = fields.Datetime(string='Check in', required=False)
to_date = fields.Datetime(string='Check out', required=False)
reg_reason = fields.Text(string='Reason', required=False)
employee = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee", default=_get_employee_id, readonly=False, required=True)
state_select = fields.Selection([('draft', 'Draft'), ('requested', 'Requested'), ('reject', 'Rejected'),
                                 ('approved', 'Approved')
                                 ], default='draft', track_visibility='onchange', string='State')
attendance_id = fields.Many2one('hr.attendance', string='Attendance')

@api.multi
def submit_reg(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    self.sudo().write({
        'state_select': 'requested'
    })
    return
   @api.multi
   def regular_approval(self):
    for record in self:
              if self.reg_category.type ==" Check in":
                    record.attendance_id.check_in = record.from_date
                    record.attendance_id.employee_id = record.employee.id
              elif self.reg_category.type ==" Check out":
                  record.attendance_id.check_out = record.to_date
                  record.attendance_id.employee_id = record.employee.id

    return  self.write({ 'state_select': 'approved' })
```

regularization.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <odoo>
   <data>
   <record id="attendance_regular11" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">attend.regular</field>
        <field name="model">attendance.regular</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <form string="Regularization">
               <header>
                       <button name="submit_reg" string="Submit" type="object" class="btn-primary"
                       attrs="{'invisible': [('state_select','not in','draft')]}"/>
                       <button name="regular_approval" type="object" string="Approve" class="oe_highlight"
                               groups="hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_manager"
                       attrs="{'invisible': [('state_select','not in','requested')]}"/>
                       <button name="regular_rejection" type="object" string="Reject" class="oe_highlight"
                               groups="hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_manager"
                       attrs="{'invisible': [('state_select','not in','requested')]}"/>
                       <field name="state_select" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,requested,approved"/>
               </header>
               <sheet>
                   <group col="4" colspan="4">
                       <field name="reg_category"/>
                       <field name="from_date" attrs="{'invisible':[('reg_category', '=',5)]}" />
                       <field name="reg_reason"/>
                       <field name="to_date" attrs="{'invisible':[('reg_category', '=',4)]}"/>
                       <field name="employee"/>

                   </group>
               </sheet>
             <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
                    <field name="activity_ids" widget="mail_activity"/>
                    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
           </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the field type you choice `fields.Many2one`.
It's should be m2m type.
I have a similar example for you.

```xml
<!--course-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="course_form_view">
     <field name="name">course.form</field>
     <field name="model">openacademy.course</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <form string="Course Form">
             <sheet>
                 <group>
                     <field name="name"/>
                     <field name="responsible_id"/>
                 </group>
                 <notebook>
                    <page string="Description">
                        <field name="description"/>
                    </page>
                    <page string="Sessions">
                        <field name="session_ids">
                             <tree string="Registered sessions">
                                 <field name="name"/>
                                 <field name="instructor_id"/>
                             </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                    <page string="About">
                        This is an example of notebooks
                    </page>
                 </notebook>
             </sheet>
         </form>
    </field>
 </record>

<!--session-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="session_form_view">
     <field name="name">session.form</field>
     <field name="model">openacademy.session</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <form string="Session Form">
             <header>
                 <button name="action_draft" type="object" string="Reset to draft" states="confirmed,done"/>
                 <button name="action_confirm" type="object" string="Confirm" states="draft" class="oe_highlight"/>
                 <button name="action_done" type="object" string="Mark as done" states="confirmed" class="oe_highlight"/>

                 <field name="state" widget="statusbar"/>
             </header>
             <sheet>
                 <group string="General">
                     <field name="course_id"  options="{'limit': 3}"/>
                     <field name="name"/>
                     <field name="instructor_id"/>
                     <field name="active"/>
                 </group>
                 <group string="Schedule">
                     <field name="start_date"/>
                     <field name="duration"/>
                     <field name="seats"/>
                     <field name="taken_seats" widget="progressbar"/>
                     <!--<button type="action" name="%(launch_session_wizard)d" string="wizard" class="oe_highlight"/>-->
                 </group>
                 <label for="attendee_ids"/>
                 <field name="attendee_ids"/>
             </sheet>
         </form>
     </field>
 </record>
```

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    _name = 'openacademy.course'

    name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
    description = fields.Text()

    responsible_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', ondelete='set null', string="Responsible", index=True)
    session_ids = fields.One2many('openacademy.session', 'course_id', string="Sessions")

    # 去改寫action的Duplicate
    @api.multi
    def copy(self, default=None):
        default = dict(default or {})

        copied_count = self.search_count([('name', '=like', u"Copy of {}%".format(self.name))])

        if not copied_count:
            new_name = u"Copy of {}".format(self.name)
        else:
            new_name = u"Copy of {} ({})".format(self.name, copied_count)

        default['name'] = new_name
        return super(Course, self).copy(default)

    # unlink 是 改寫Action的Delete

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('name_description_check',
         'CHECK(name != description)',
         "The title of the course should not be the description"),
        ('name_unique',
         'UNIQUE(name)',
         "The course title must be unique"),
    ]


class Session(models.Model):
    _name = 'openacademy.session'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    start_date = fields.Date(default=fields.Date.today)
    duration = fields.Float(digits=(6, 2), help="Duration in days")
    seats = fields.Integer(string="Number of seats")
    active = fields.Boolean(default=True)
    color = fields.Integer()

    instructor_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Instructor", domain=['|', ('instructor', '=', True), ('category_id.name', 'ilike', "Teacher")])
    course_id = fields.Many2one('openacademy.course', ondelete='cascade', string="Course", required=True)
    attendee_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner', string="Attendees")
    taken_seats = fields.Float(string="Taken seats", compute='_taken_seats')
    end_date = fields.Date(string="End Date", store=True, compute='_get_end_date', inverse='_set_end_date')
    hours = fields.Float(string="Duration in hours", compute='_get_hours', inverse='_set_hours')
    attendees_count = fields.Integer(string="Attendees count", compute='_get_attendees_count', store=True)
    state = fields.Selection([('draft', "Draft"),('confirmed', "Confirmed"),('done', "Done"),], default='draft')

    @api.multi
    def action_draft(self):
        self.state = 'draft'

    @api.multi
    def action_confirm(self):
        self.state = 'confirmed'

    @api.multi
    def action_done(self):
        self.state = 'done'

    @api.depends('seats', 'attendee_ids')
    def _taken_seats(self):
        for r in self:
            if not r.seats:
                r.taken_seats = 0.0
            else:
                r.taken_seats = 100.0 * len(r.attendee_ids) / r.seats

    @api.depends('attendee_ids')
    def _get_attendees_count(self):
        for r in self:
            r.attendees_count = len(r.attendee_ids)

    @api.depends('duration')
    def _get_hours(self):
        for r in self:
            r.hours = r.duration * 24

    def _set_hours(self):
        for r in self:
            r.duration = r.hours / 24

    @api.depends('start_date', 'duration')
    def _get_end_date(self):
        for r in self:
            if not (r.start_date and r.duration):
                r.end_date = r.start_date
                continue
            start = fields.Datetime.from_string(r.start_date)
            duration = timedelta(days=r.duration, seconds=-1)
            r.end_date = start + duration

    def _set_end_date(self):
        for r in self:
            if not (r.start_date and r.end_date):
                continue
            start_date = fields.Datetime.from_string(r.start_date)
            end_date = fields.Datetime.from_string(r.end_date)
            r.duration = (end_date - start_date).days + 1

    @api.onchange('seats', 'attendee_ids')
    def _verify_valid_seats(self):
        if self.seats < 0:
            return {
                'warning': {
                    'title': "Incorrect 'seats' value",
                    'message': "The number of available seats may not be negative",
                },
            }

        if self.seats < len(self.attendee_ids):
            return {
                'warning': {
                    'title': "Too many attendees",
                    'message': "Increase seats or remove excess attendees",
                },
            }

    @api.constrains('instructor_id', 'attendee_ids')
    def _check_instructor_not_in_attendees(self):
        for r in self:
            if r.instructor_id and r.instructor_id in r.attendee_ids:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError("A session's instructor can't be an attendee")
```